# Best way to calculate the IC50 with limit contraints in drc::drm()

Tags: r, drc

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Conc = c(0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 
0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 
0.25, 0.5, 1, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 0.03125, 
0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 
1), Response = c(167.11246201, 53.96960486, 128.42857143, 43.67173252, 
4.51975684, 0.34042553, 120.10334347, 101.14589666, 155.17629179, 
35.31306991, 8.56534954, 1.7112462, 146.34954407, 108.50151976, 
163.60182371, 64.70212766, 2.88145897, 0.50759878, 82.92401216, 
109.80547112, 116.69300912, 26.85410334, 3.01519757, 0.37386018, 
87.06990881, 84.82978723, 118.36474164, 27.52279635, 2.34650456, 
0.10638298, 89.47720365, 109.47112462, 85.43161094, 17.69300912, 
2.31306991, 0.07294833)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Once I try to set the parameters without knowing what I am really doing

```
library(drc)

fit <- drm(formula = Response ~ Conc, data = df,
               fct = LL.4(names=c("Slope","Lower Limit","Upper Limit", "EC50")))
```

Once I let the package to select it for me without knowing what it's doing

```
fit2 <- drm(formula = Response ~ Conc, data = df, 
           fct = LL.4(names=c("Slope","Lower Limit","Upper Limit", "EC50")),
           lowerl = c(-Inf, 0, min(df$Response), 0), 
           upperl = c(Inf, min(df$Conc), max(df$Conc), Inf))
```

Can someone help me to understand this ?

Then I see the results are completely different and I personally don't know which way to select the parameters

```
plot(fit, main = paste("ED(drm, 50):", ED(fit, 50)[[1]]))
plot(fit2, main = paste("ED(drm, 50):", ED(fit2, 50)[[1]]))
```

Comment: Where does `drm` come from?

Comment: it comes from `library(drc)`

Comment: @Learner I was trying to recommend GRmetrics but it requires an input that contains specific information and so would be more hassle to you than use. I have therefore removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the limits in `upperl` and `lowerl` you are constraining the paramater estimates. Here the upper limit in `fit2` for the "Upper Limit" parameter is set way to low (see the curve is a flat line). If you adjust that to something closer to the observed data then the EC-50 estimate gets a lot closer to `fit`.

```
fit3 <- drm(formula = Response ~ Conc, data = df, 
            fct = LL.4(names=c("Slope","Lower Limit","Upper Limit", "EC50")),
            lowerl = c(-Inf, 0, min(df$Response), 0), 
            upperl = c(Inf, min(df$Conc), max(df$Response) - 10, Inf))

plot(fit3, main = paste("ED(drm, 50):", ED(fit, 50)[[1]]))
```

FWIW when I use `drc::drm()` I rarely set these limits. The only reason to set them is if you have prior/expert knowledge about how the dose response behaves and the model estimate is violating that. In a case like this, where you have values in the upper plateau and lower plateau, the default arguments will do a good job estimating the EC-50.

Comment: how did you set the lower and upper values? can you please tell me how to calculate IC50 too? or do you know how to calculate AUC as well?